Как правильно передать данные из приложения на NodeJS в десктоп приложение .exe (tauri + react)
У меня есть приложение, в котором я формирую данные. Работает там код Node JS. Результатом является объект. Из кода я запускаю скомпилированные приложение - это tauri с использованием React (хочу написать такое приложения для обработки и визуализации полученных данных). Под капотом у этого приложения Rust.
Вопрос в том, что необходимо написать в файле main.rs, чтобы принять данные из другого приложения. Прошу не судить строго, я только в начале этого пути. Вот код по умолчанию в файле main.rs:
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

// Learn more about Tauri commands at https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command
#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
  format!("Hello, {}! You've been greeted from Rust!", name)
}

fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

